# Discord bot doesn't send a greeting message

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

The problem is that Discord bot doesn't send the greeting message when a new member joins.

node version is 16

discord.js is v13

The terminal shows no errors.
And this is the code:

```
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember=>{
    const User = guildMember.user
        const channel = guildMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == '798928691988004897');
        
        console.log(User)
    
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Welcome')
            .setDescription(`Welcome to the server <@${User.id}>`)
            .setThumbnail(`${User.avatarURL()}`)
        
            channel.send({embeds :[embed]});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do not have the "guild member" intents enabled for the bot to detect changes made to guild members

go to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and navigate to your application and enable `server member` intent
[image: Developer Portal > Bot App > Bot > Enable Server member intent]

And you need to have this intent enabled within your code as well

```js
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js'); // require other classes as per your bot needs
const intents = [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]; // Add other related intents
const bot = new Client({ intents: intents });

// finish your code with events and stuff
```

Comment: So it will be like this:
`const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js'); 
const bot = new Client({ intents: intents });

const Discord = require('discord.js')

const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });`
@EJBEAN
Right?

Comment: i've already declared the bot constant, you don't need to declare it again

Comment: `{intents: intents}` is unneeded. Just put `{ intents }`